# Firebase ios select from database where value equals to something

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database and want to get the values from the DB into swift but I need to filter the data as I have 2 types of data `Inc` and `Exp` how can I create a query for Firebase that will select all the fields where `Type = Exp` for example

Here is how my DB looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you get your response from firebase as an Array, you can do

```
response = response.filter({yourItem.type == "Exp"})
```